# Are there tricks for doing implicit conversions in F#?

Tags: f#

Consider this F# code to sum the numbers below `i` that are multiples of 3 and 5:

```
let isMultipleOfThreeOrFive n = 
    (n % 3 = 0) || (n % 5 = 0)

let sequenceOfMultiples i =
    seq {1 .. i - 1} |> Seq.filter isMultipleOfThreeOrFive
```

Since `i` is an `int`, you'll overflow if `i` is large.  This version with `BigInteger` takes care of that:

```
let isMultipleOfThreeOrFive n = 
    (n % 3I = 0I) || (n % 5I = 0I)

let sequenceOfMultiples (i : System.Numerics.BigInteger) =
    seq {1I .. i - 1I} |> Seq.filter isMultipleOfThreeOrFive
```

To convert the `int` version to the `BigInteger` version, I had to add lots of `I`s after the numbers.  This is because F# doesn't do implicit conversions.

Is there an easy way to get around this, or was adding `I`s in 6 places the best thing to do?

Comment: it's not a bug, it's a feature ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did the best thing.

(There is not an easier way to "get around" it than by adding the six characters you added.  Even without implicit conversions, the F# is shorter than the C#, and the delta change-from-int-to-BigInteger is also smaller in F# than C#.  So don't be sad about the loss of implicit conversion - be happy about all the other succinctness wins. :) )

Comment: Speed loses big time however.

Comment: Huh?  The F# BigInteger and C# BigInteger code do the same work?

Comment: Thanks, Brian.  Always a pleasure reading your stuff here and on reddit.

Comment: going 'generic' statically would have made the trick though I think, as F# can specialize the code to the specific type at hand at compile time

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but note that it's also possible to make `sequenceOfMultiples` generic by defining your own numeric literal:

```
module NumericLiteralG =
  let inline FromZero() = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
  let inline FromOne() = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
  let inline FromInt32 (i:int) =
    let zero : ^a = FromZero()
    let one : ^a = FromOne()
    let rec compute : int -> ^a = function
    | 0 -> zero
    | n -> 
        let half = compute (n/2)
        let whole = half + half
        if (n%2 = 0) then whole
        else whole + one
    compute i

let inline isMultipleOfThreeOrFive n = 
    (n % 3G = 0G) || (n % 5G = 0G)

let inline sequenceOfMultiples i =
    seq {1G .. i - 1G} |> Seq.filter isMultipleOfThreeOrFive

let bigintSeq = sequenceOfMultiples 100I
let intSeq = sequenceOfMultiples 100

// doesn't compile
let stringSeq = sequenceOfMultiples "100"
```