# Function working for all numerical data types

Tags: f#, inline, generic-programming

I've written a simple function that reverses a given number:

```
let reverseNumber x =
    let rec innerFunc acc elem =
        if elem = 0
            then acc
            else 
                let rem = elem % 10
                innerFunc (10 * acc + rem) (elem / 10)

    innerFunc 0 x
```

The problem is it works only with ints. For e.g. int64 I need to create another version that uses `0L` and `10L` instead of `0` and `10` respectively.

I've heard it's possible to write more generic functions using inline keyword and LanguagePrimitives, but the latter doesn't contain neither reminder operation nor 'GenericTen' (although this might be obtained by 'GenericOne + GenericOne + ... ).

Could you help ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4078150/82959, but note that it doesn't properly handle negative literals (for that, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4741799/82959).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring the completeness of @kvb's linked answers, this is the minimal work to make it generic:

```
module NumericLiteralG =
    let inline FromZero () = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    let inline FromOne () = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne

let inline reverseNumber (x:^a) =
    let ten:^a = 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G + 1G
    let rec innerFunc (acc:^a) (elem:^a) =
        if elem = 0G then acc
        else
            let (rem:^a) = elem % ten
            innerFunc (ten * acc + rem) (elem / ten)
    innerFunc 0G x
```

The type annotations are not strictly necessary, and are only present to reduce the type constraints listed in IntelliSense; the code would work identically without them.